# How to disable an option in a drop down list so that arrow keys skip to the next available option?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown list where I need to be able to disable certain options for arrow-keys so that when pressed it skips the disabled options and goes to the next available one.

[here is an example with bootstrap.](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/bootstrap/bootstrap_3/tutorial/bootstrap_3_dropdowns_disabled_menu_items) The problem is this dropdown is part of a library so I can't just use bootstrap

Comment: "this dropdown is part of a library"... well, we're not going to be able to help without knowing what that library is, unless it's a plain `select`. It would be great if you could show us a [mcve] demonstrating the issue you're having and what you've tried to fix this yourself...

Comment: It's an `<ul>` list. It's the autocomplete dropdown menu from codemirror.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `disabled` attribute to that option.

```html
<select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option disabled>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The problem is it's an It's an `<ul>` list. I tried disabled but that didn't work